# ajustar tamaño del texto de un spinner

Tags: android, android-studio

que tal. Tengo un spinner tal que asi:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/frecuencia"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100px"
    android:backgroundTint="#009688"
    android:padding="25px" />
```

y queria aumentar el tamaño del texto, pero no encuentro manera. ¿como puedo aumentar el tamaño del texto de un spinner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9476736/16597055 Podrias probar esto.

Comment: he probado tal y como dice ese post con `android:textSize="20sp"` pero no funciona

Comment: Tienes que crear un adaptador o un TextVIew para asignarle estilos y demases a tu Spinner. Saludos

Comment: Opcion 1: Usar AutoCompleteTextView de Material Android para lanzar una lista seleccionable. Opcion 2: Ajustar el android.R.layout.tu_estilo.xml para el spinner en el adapter   ArrayAdapter<Model> adapterModel = new ArrayAdapter<Model>(this, android.R.layout.tu_estilo);
        adapterProv.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.u_estilo);